# How to setup/debug github WebHook?

Tags: github

I have this local repo, I make changes and run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

My github has two WebHooks set-up, one going to a http://requestb.in URL and another one going to a PHP executable script (755), in the same folder (accessible from outside).

The PHP script:

```
<?php echo `git pull origin master`; 
// echo "works"; 
// echo `whoami` ?>
```

The commented test lines are working so this is my proof that the script path is OK and also the syntax.

However, after I push changes from local to github repo, I check files on the server but nothing happens, is obvious echo `git pull origin master` from my PHP script does nothing.

If I run this in a shell logged as a root (git pull origin master), the files are getting updated with the latest version from the repo.

Also, the second hook I have set-up, the one from requestb.in works as I can see the requests from github.

My folder on the server has the right permission, is accessible form the outside, I am desperate and I don't know how to get this working.

**What is wrong, how can I make this working? How do I set-up the WebHook in the admin panel in github**, or is it the PHP script, is there a permissions issue, what's wrong?! :O

Thank you.

Update after my 3 comments:
After dealing with it for couple more hours, I can clearly see that the WebHook doesn't really fire up the php file. If I run in shell logged as a root "php test.php" I get:

```
root@echo [/home/moove/public_html/dev/wert]# php hooh.php 
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From github.com:chrisdemetriad/wert
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 0c67b85..89e4fdf
Fast-forward
 XXX.php |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
root@echo [/home/moove/public_html/dev/wert]#
```

Which is what I need and the files on the server get updated. But if I don't do it manually, the files do not get updated and this must be because of the php script. My latest version that works:

```
<?php echo `git pull origin master`;
```

Comment: I've been thinking of it.. when I output whoami from the php script, works, so whatever is inbetween `` gets executed and also the requestbin link works; it must be a problem of who has the rights to access the php script.. right? but that is visible from the outside worls! I don't understand :/

Comment: I think I figured out what my problem is.. after doing it in console all day long, I've now realised I am being asked for the password (Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':), and I don't have that in my php script.. how stupid of me. How to do go about it as an approach similar to echo `git pull origin master`; echo `password`; doesn't work?

Comment: I've realised I have to set up a passphrase. I've done that passphrase thing and it has worked but now.. Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
./sh.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory

Comment: @C D Sorry to necro this after four years, but did you ever figure out exactly how to resolve this issue? I am having the exact same problem, and experiencing the exact same frustrations as you. From your comments, it looks like you determined that you needed to add a password somewhere, but then ran into a new issue.

Comment: No worries @cag8f, it's been a while really but all I can remember is a permissions issue, not sure whether this is accurate after reading my comments. Sorry!